Estimates for number of primes satisfying certain quadratic residuosity condition
Given a square-free integer $d$, how many primes $p<d$ such that $p$ is a quadratic residue modulo $d$ and $\left(\frac{d}{p}\right)=1$?
Also, what are the estimates for the same problem with primes $p$ that are quadratic non-residue modulo $d$ and $\left(\frac{d}{p}\right)=1$?
I should note that I’m looking for conditional result upon GRH, and accordingly I know that there are $\frac{1}{2^{\omega(d)}}Li(d) +O(d^{1/2}\log d)$ primes less than $d$ that are quadratic residues modulo $d$ using an effective version of Chebotarev density’s theorem. So I want to have an estimates for the number of those primes for which $\left(\frac{d}{p}\right)=1$.
Heuristically, half of those primes $p$ from the Chebotarev density theorem should satisfy $\left(\frac{d}{p}\right)=1$.

Please use a high-level tag like "nt.number-theory". I added this tag now. Regarding high-level tags, see https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/1075/

First a correction to your post. The correct density (in the situation you describe) is not
$$\frac{d}{2^{\omega(d)}\log d} +O(d^{1/2}\log d)$$
but
$$\frac{1}{2^{\omega(d)}}\mathrm{li}(d) +O(d^{1/2}\log d).\tag{$\ast$}$$
Note that the difference between $\mathrm{li(d)}$ and $d/\log d$ is asymptotically $d/\log^2 d$, a quantity much larger than the error terms above. Also, the error term in $(\ast)$ can be divided by $2^{\omega(d)}$ by Theorem 1.1 in this paper by Lagarias-Odlyzko.
Now to your question. Let us assume for simplicity that $d$ is odd (the case of even $d$ can be treated similarly). If $p>2$ is a quadratic residue modulo $d$, then $\left(\frac{d}{p}\right)=(-1)^{(d-1)(p-1)/4}$ by the law of quadratic reciprocity for the Jacobi symbol. So if $d\equiv 1\pmod{4}$, then $\left(\frac{d}{p}\right)=1$ is automatic, while if $d\equiv 3\pmod{4}$, then $\left(\frac{d}{p}\right)=\left(\frac{-1}{p}\right)$. In the latter case, one can apply the above quoted theorem of Lagarias-Odlyzko (for the number field generated by the square-roots of the prime divisors of $d$ and also $\sqrt{-1}$) to obtain
$$2^{-1-\omega(d)}\mathrm{li}(d)+O(2^{-\omega(d)}d^{1/2}\log d)$$
for the number of primes $p<d$ in question.
One can also argue more directly, without using Jacobi's reciprocity theorem. Let $d$ have prime factorization $q_1\dotsb q_r$, and let $q^*$ abbreviate $(-1)^{(q-1)/2}q$. Then, $(\ast)$ is obtained by applying the quoted theorem of Lagarias-Odlyzko to the number field
$$F=\mathbb{Q}\bigl(\sqrt{q_1^*},\dotsc,\sqrt{q_r^*}\bigr).$$
Now $d^*=q_1^\ast\dotsb q_r^*$, whence $\sqrt{d}$ lies in $F$ if and only if $d\equiv 1\pmod{4}$.

Thank you so much @GHfromMO!! I just have a question, how would the second approach give the additional 1/2 coefficient in the main term, i.e how does it really follow? Would really appreciate it!

@mahermamah The point is that the conditions are equivalent to splitting of $p$ in $F(\sqrt{d})$, so the question is what is the degree of this number field. If $d\equiv 1\pmod{4}$, then $\sqrt{d}\in F$, so the degree is $2^{\omega(d)}$. If $d\equiv 3\pmod{4}$, then $\sqrt{d}\not\in F$, so the degree is $2^{1+\omega(d)}$.

I just have one last question, what about the case when p is a quadratic non-residue mod d and the jacobi symbol could be potentially negative, don’t we need d and p to be both congruent to 3 mod 4?

@mahermamah I am not sure I understand your question. Your original post was restricted to quadratic residues modulo $d$, so why should we consider quadratic non-residues modulo $d$? At any rate, if you have a new question, please ask it in a new post.

thank you so much for your assistance so far. In the question I asked in the post it was two parts. The first one asked about primes that are quadratic residues mod d and the other one is one primes p that are quadratic non residues..

@mahermamah I see. Two remarks. It is general policy here to restrict to one question per post. At any rate, if by "quadratic non-residue modulo $d$" you mean "not a quadratic residue modulo $d$", then the answer is easy: just take the asymptotic formula for the number of primes $p<d$ satisfying $\left(\frac{d}{p}\right)=1$, and subtract from it the answer for your first question. So the answer is (under GRH): $(2^{-1}-2^{-\omega(d)})\mathrm{li}(d)+O(d^{1/2}\log d)$ when $d\equiv 1\pmod{4}$ and $(2^{-1}-2^{-1-\omega(d)})\mathrm{li}(d)+O(d^{1/2}\log d)$ when $d\equiv 3\pmod{4}$.

Thank you so much @GHfromMO!! I really appreciate your help a lot! I wish I can vote your answer up, but still need to build up my reputation :)

I'm sorry to bother but would like to ask about the case where d is even, as all that doesn't really apply directly...really thankful!

@mahermamah If $d=2q_1\dotsb q_r$ is even, then the condition is equivalent to the splitting of $p$ in the number field $F(\sqrt{d})$, where $F$ is in my post. Now $\sqrt{d}\not\in F$, hence the relative density is $2^{-r-1}=2^{-\omega(d)}$. Note that the relative density of primes $p<d$ which are quadratic residues modulo $d$ is $2^{-r}=2^{1-\omega(d)}$ in this case (these are the primes splitting in $F$).
